# How to fetch fields that require access token using fbgraph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, fb-graph

I am trying to fields that require access token, fields like age_range, here are the list of fields

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

```
user = FbGraph::User.new('me', :access_token => access_token).fetch
```

I am trying

```
 user.age_range #=> nil
```

Where as when i am trying in facebook graph api explorer using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

```
facebook_id?fields=age_range
```

It shows the Json data for the same user.

Comment: nice question!!! any buddy answering !!!

I also need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it using omniauth ,Added info_fields with scope

```
provider :facebook, facebook_app_id, facebook_secret_key, { :info_fields => 'age_range', :scope => 'email,offline_access' }
```